# Why does my form get pushed on error?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that uses [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). I am using the form with bootstrap but every time an error is displayed the form gets pushed over to the right. Can anyone show me how to stop this? I've made a [demo here](http://codepen.io/julianj/pen/aNaLJe).

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#message").hide();

  //Define your validation rules.
  $("#bill_cost").validate({
    expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Should be a number"
  });

  //Define the event that will occur when the entire form is validated (on form submission)
  $('#myform').validated(function(){
    var formdata = $('#myform').serialize();

    //Post form data
    $.post('#', formdata, function(data){
      //Process post response
      $("#message").html(data);
      $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
      $("#message").fadeOut(500); 
    });

    //Reset Form
    $('#myform')[0].reset(); 
  });

});
```

The form

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" method="post">

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" id="submitButtonId" name="submit1"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't see any console errors.

Comment: my guess is that this is caused by the span appended when you get error. check the span that contains `Should be a number` i hope it helps

Comment: `Why does my form get pushed on error?`

Because when you get error displayed under your input there is no room for the new `span` tag with error to accommodate, So it takes the next line and UI gets messed up..

Comment: It does this because you've specified `col-md-8` - col-md is for medium width columns and, on a full screen, it's simply not wide enough for the input and the message span.

You can see this by submitting to get the error and then resizing the window so it's much smaller.